# Does flutter unity widget works on unity 2d?

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine

Im student from Malaysia currently working on my project.

My project is developed using flutter and unity 2d and I need to embed unity 2d into flutter project. I have been wondering if flutter unity widget works on unity 2d as well?

Your answer are appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible, because unlike the Godot engine, unity uses the same engine for both 2D and 3D development.